# Python program to print fibonacci series using lambda function in Python

Tags: python, lambda, fibonacci

I have found this code online but not sure what does "any" do there!?

```
def fibonacci(count):
    fib_list = [0, 1]
    any(map(lambda _: fib_list.append(sum(fib_list[-2:])),
                                     range(2, count)))
    return fib_list[:count]
print(fibonacci(20))
```

Comment: `any` will loop through the iterable until the first True value.  In this case the iterable is the result of `map` which will never be True, since `fib_list.append` is always None.  Thus, any causes the complete iterable  to be looped over.  In this case, `any` could be replaced by `list` with the same result.

Comment: `map` returns a a lazy iterator. For it to iterate, there needs to be a consumer. `any` plays that role here. This still abuses a generator/comprehension for side effects and should be considered an anti-pattern

Comment: A good example of how to write simple code in the most obscure way...

Comment: Why fib_list.apppend is always none? Will you please explain??

Answer (score 0):

In essence, the `any` function will keep looping through the iterable input until a value is true. The input is the result of map which won't ever be True since fib_list.append is always None.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the code you can just tuple or list and print the map values:

```
    def fibonacci(count):
    fib_list = [0, 1]
    print(tuple(map(lambda _: fib_list.append(sum(fib_list[-2:])),range(2, count))))
    return fib_list[:count]
    print(fibonacci(20))

    #output
    (None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None)
    [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181]
```

You can skip `any` if you want and replace it with a tuple or list

Link to `any` documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=any#any

Answer (score 0):

The any() function forces the lambda to run through every element of the iterator.  It is a bit of a hack to loop without a for-loop statement.

For a cleaner approach, you could use recursion and provide the starting value convention as parameter (0,1: modern) or (1,1: ancient):

```
fibo = lambda n,a,b: [a]+fibo(n-1,b,a+b) if n>1 else [a]
```

output:

```
print(*fibo(10,0,1))

0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34

print(*fibo(10,1,1))

1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55
```

If you don't want to use recursion, you can make it a list comprehension:

```
fibo = lambda n: [ab.append(sum(ab)) or ab.pop(0) 
                  for ab in [[0,1]] for _ in range(n)]

print(*fibo(10))

0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34
```